# Multiple Inheritance and variable access issue with Python v2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm wondering about this issue I'm getting with Python, I'm sure this is well known.  I've been dabbling in Python now for a while and am getting used to it's flavor but I'm running into this issue outlined below.  If you run this code below:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_var = 1


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar_var = 2
        super(Foo, self).__init__()

    def deep_access(self):
        pp(self.bar_var)


class FooBar(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foobar_var = 3
        super(Bar, self).__init__()

    def access(self):
        # call Bar
        self.deep_access()

fb = FooBar()
fb.access()
```

You will receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inheritance.py", line 29, in <module>
    fb.access()
  File "inheritance.py", line 26, in access
    self.deep_access()
  File "inheritance.py", line 16, in deep_access
    pp(self.bar_var)
AttributeError: 'FooBar' object has no attribute 'bar_var'
```

From the error I gather it's looking for bar_var in FooBar rather than Bar, but if I call the parent class, why not use the variable declared in the parent??  How do I get a parent class to access it's own variables?  It just seems weird to me coming from a different approach to OOP.

Instead of `self.deep_access` it tried `Bar.deep_access(self)` and `super(FooBar, self).deep_access` and `super(Bar, self).deep_access` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `super()` correctly.  The first argument should always be the class that's *calling* super, not any of its base classes..

change

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar_var = 2
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
#             ^^^
```

to

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar_var = 2
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
#             ^^^
```

and so on...

There's a nice article explaining most of the ins and outs of `super()` called ["Super considered Super!"](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: Oh for lord christ haha.  Thanks.  This is the correct answer.  Currently reading the article, looks good!